# How to add a potential term to the Dirac Equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, dirac-equation, gauge

I've read that if you have a Hamiltonian for the [Dirac Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation), you can add a potential term to it simply by adjusting the momentum operator so that $p^\mu \rightarrow p^\mu-A^\mu$, where $A^\mu$ is the relevant potential. But how do you calculate $A^\mu$? For example, what would $A^\mu$ be for an electron in an electromagnetic field given by the tensor $F^{\alpha\beta}$?

Comment: Use the classical vector potential (the one you get from maxwell equations in potential form), but the correct tools for that situation should be  quantum field theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field tensor can be derived from the vector potential like so:

$$F^{\mu \nu}=\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^{\nu}A^\mu $$

If $F$ is simple enough, you can usually construct an appropriate $A$ without too much difficulty. Otherwise you're stuck inverting this with a bunch of indefinite integrals.

Note that $A$ is not uniquely determined by this relation. If $A^\mu$ is a valid vector potential, then for any analytic function $\phi$ $$A'^\mu=A^\mu + \partial^\mu\phi $$
will give equivalent results.